# always mandatory or sometimes optional?

Tags: objective-c, init

As i was reading through the book on `Objective-C`, i came across an example that initialized a class as follows:

```
ClassName *p = [[ClassName alloc] init];
```

While it makes sense that first we need to allocate memory to store data `ClassName` has before initializing, the following works just as well:

```
ClassName *p = [ClassName alloc];
```

Is `init` always needed?

Comment: Interestingly enough, would there be any case where not using `init` might be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, it's not technically required. That's because `NSObject`'s `init` method is effectively just `return self;`. However, in practice, it's **absolutely** essential. Objects perform internal setup inside the `init` method - creating internal state, allocating private members, and generally getting ready for action. The `init` method may not even return the same object as you allocated.

Think of it in two phases: `alloc` allocates memory, but that's it - it's analogous to Java's `new`. `init` configures the  state of the memory so that the object can perform it's tasks - analogous to Java calling the constructor. Don't leave it out!

Comment: `alloc` also performs the important step of setting the `isa` pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. And you're right. Strictly speacking "init" is not required.
"alloc" does three important things to create an object:
- allocate enough memory to hold all instance variables
- initialize the "isa" instance variable
- all other instances are set to 0

Consider that the "root" Cocoa object, NSObject, simply returns "self" in its init method.

But, if you want to be a good Obj-C citizen, you must use "init". It is part of the "contract" between you, the developer, and the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should always call one of the initializer methods especially when the class isn't your own. The pointer returned from `init` isn't necessarily the same as returned by `alloc`.

Read the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-init